# Conditional Formatting of maximum value in each row of many

Tags: excel, max, excel-2013, conditional-formatting, rule

I have a spreadsheet with 250+ rows of data and need to find the largest value in each row. I tried to use Conditional Formatting, however I need the same rule for each row so can't highlight all the data, and trying to copy and paste it would be too cumbersome.

Is there a faster way of applying the same rule to each row separately?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please select he relevant columns (say A:H) and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=A1=MAX($A1:$H1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your choice of formatting, OK, OK.

If you want the formatting to stop when there are no values in the row adjust to:

```
 =AND(COUNT($A1:$H1)<>0,A1=MAX($A1:$H1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Formula: =A1=MAX(A:A)  (don’t use $)

Applies To: =$A:$D

[image]

To shift columns, change the starting point of the formula AND the “Applies To” range.

Formula: =C1=MAX(C:C)  (don’t use $)

Applies To: =$C:$F

[image]

Formula: =A2=MAX(2:2)  (don’t use $)

Applies To: =$2:$11

*Shift first row down to adjust for header row

[image]

Finally, as [pnuts shows in the post above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33962170/4831894), to correct for cell overflow into blanks cells/rows/columns (shown here)

[image]

Use the following variation:

*(the same for rows/columns and MIN/MAX)*

Formula: =AND(COUNT(C:C)<>0,C1=MAX(C:C))  (don’t use $)

Applies To: =$C:$F